# Mask mobile 6 digit with * n show last 4 digits in EditText Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

[image: Mask number like this in EditText]

How can I mask Mobile Starting digits in Android EdiiText.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make a class like this

```
public class ChangeTransformationMethod extends PasswordTransformationMethod {
    @Override
    public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
        return new PasswordCharSequence(source);
    }

    private class PasswordCharSequence implements CharSequence {
        private CharSequence mSource;
        public PasswordCharSequence(CharSequence source) {
            mSource = source; 
        }
        public char charAt(int index) {
            if(index <=5)
                return 'N'; 
            else
                return mSource.charAt(index);
        }
        public int length() {
            return mSource.length(); 
        }
        public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
            return mSource.subSequence(start, end); 
        }
    }
}
```

then set it on your EditText like this:

```
editText.setTransformationMethod(new ChangeTransformationMethod());
```

Comment: So how can I get actual number?

Comment: it does not change number. You can get number as a String simply by editText.getText().toString();